# MySQL select with datetime comparison in WHERE clause causes PHP error

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a MySQL select query with few joins and multiple conditions in WHERE clause. I am having a trouble comparing columns `datestart` and `dateend`.
These can either fit into given term, or be null. MySQL data type of both is `datetime`.
The problematic part of query is the following: `AND (a.datestart > '".$datestart."' AND a.dateend < '".$dateend."') OR (a.datestart > '".$datestart."' AND a.dateend is null) OR (a.datestart is null AND a.dateend < '".$dateend."') OR (a.datestart is null AND a.dateend is null))`
If I run the query without this part, it runs fine. If with, I get the following error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object` on line `while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc())`.
I already use the `a.something` syntax earlier in the query, so the join works fine.
Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Posting the whole query on request (not from the code, but an example with specific sample values. If you need the php code, I will add it as well).

```
SELECT a.id AS id, t.title AS title, t.shortDescription AS shortDescription, p.prices_value AS prices_value, c.symbol AS symbol, a.rating AS rating FROM tblactivity a inner join tblactivitytranslations t on a.id = t.activityId inner join tblprices p on a.price = p.id inner join tblcurrencies c on p.currency = c.id WHERE t.lang = '0' AND t.title LIKE '%Some%' AND p.currency = '0' AND (false or (prices_value >= 0 and prices_value <= 25) or (prices_value >= 25 and prices_value <= 50) or (prices_value >= 50 and prices_value <= 75) or (prices_value >= 75 and prices_value <= 100) or (prices_value >= 100)) AND (a.datestart > '2000-1-1' AND a.dateend < '2079-1-1') OR (a.datestart > '2000-1-1' AND a.dateend is null) OR (a.datestart is null AND a.dateend < '2079-1-1') OR (a.datestart is null AND a.dateend is null))
```

Comment: Could it be that `FROM tblactivity a inner join` should be `FROM tblactivity inner join`?

Comment: i don't think so. If I remove the whole date part (the query ends after `or (prices_value >= 100))`), the query works without errors and returns correct data, exactly as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Check your SQL query again. Your parentheses in the `WHERE` clause are not adding up. You end on a double parenthesis after null without a paired opening parenthesis.

Also, there's a `false` hanging out with no defined column (this may be a typo on the SO post since you mentioned you took off the last statement and all ran fine).

By the way, your WHERE clause may have redundancy. One of the conditions on prices_value:

```
(prices_value >= 0 and prices_value <= 25) 
or (prices_value >= 25 and prices_value <= 50) 
or (prices_value >= 50 and prices_value <= 75) 
or (prices_value >= 75 and prices_value <= 100) 
or (prices_value >= 100)
```

could be combined across all OR clauses into one inclusive condition since all endpoints connect and goes beyond 100:

```
(prices_value >= 0)
```